# How can I subseq a sorted-map that uses tick LocalDate as a key?

Tags: clojure

It is possible to subseq a sorted collection in clojure like so:

```clj
(subseq (sorted-map-by clojure.core/< 1 :a 2 :b 3 :c) clojure.core/> 1)
=> ([2 :b] [3 :c])
```

If I use java.time.LocalDate as the key of the map using [tick](https://www.juxt.land/tick/docs/index.html), then the subseq gives an error:

```clj
(require '[tick.alpha.api :as t :refer :all])
(let [m (sorted-map-by t/< 
                      (t/date "2021-01-01") :a
                      (t/date "2021-02-02") :b 
                      (t/date "2021-03-03") :c )]
  (clojure.core/subseq m t/< (t/date "2021-01-15")))
Error printing return value (IllegalArgumentException) at clojure.core/-cache-protocol-fn (core_deftype.clj:583).
No implementation of method: :< of protocol: #'tick.core/ITimeComparison found for class: java.lang.Integer
```

How can I subseq a sorted-map with java.time.LocalDate keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs of [subseq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/subseq),
the `test` parameter of the function must be one of `<, <=, > or >=`.

This is because it will be used to compare `0` to the result of the sorted collection's comparator function called on the elements. <s>(Remember that `<` returns boolean values, however, `t/<` returns an integer.)</s>

So instead of

```
(clojure.core/subseq m t/< (t/date "2021-01-15"))
```

Write:

```
(clojure.core/subseq m < (t/date "2021-01-15"))
```

Comment: Good answer - your recommendation works and I understand why.  The statement about t/< returning an integer is not true though.. (t/< (t/date "2021-01-01") (t/date "2020-01-01"))
=> false

Comment: you are right. it compares values given by the 3-way comparator (which returns int) produced using clojure.core/comparator using the collection's own boolean comparator.